# opscenter backup fails while trying to snapshot and non-existing SStable

Tags: backup, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm running a DSE cluster in AWS: `m2.4xlarge` instances running Datastax Enterprise 4.6.1, with Cassandra 2.0.12.200 and Opscenter 5.1.0.

When we try to do a backup of a keyspace, we get this:

```
Snapshot of keyspaces [XXXXXXX] on node XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX failed: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Tried to hard link to file that does not exist /raid0/cassandra/data/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX-jb-1-Index.db
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely the following known issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6433

The workaround for this is a rolling restart and it is fixed in c* 2.1. It seems to be caused when you drop a keyspace and re-create it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a dropped keyspace and compaction.

Run a "nodetool repair" and check the "system" and "opscenter" keyspaces for traces of the deleted keyspace. You might need to manually remove stale rows.